# Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid. While trying to get the token

Tags: .net, cookies, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, webapi

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIbFm.png)I am trying to get the access token using .net core web api code implementation, but getting some issue. This is my code. Please let me know where I am wrong or something needs to be changed.

```
    [HttpPost("accessToken")]
    public ActionResult GetToken()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/oauth2/token");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "aapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      //request.AddHeader("Cookie", "");
        request.AddParameter("code", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("client_id", "60b***********************8ng");
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", "dl***************************aph");
        request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "http://localhost");
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        request.AddParameter("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var result = client.Execute(request);
       // Console.Write()
        return Ok(response.Content);
    }


    [When try to send the request on postman getting this issue][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reaching out, could please try by removing  the below code
request.AddParameter("code", "application/json");

Thanks